# VB.NET get only a square from picture

Tags: vb.net, pixel, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VB.NET replace pixel color of picturebox image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871809/vb-net-replace-pixel-color-of-picturebox-image)

i want to extract square from full picture
full pic:

[image: full pic]

i want only this:

[image: expected]

Comment: i want to extract square and remove the white color split the picture

Comment: You want to remove every white pixel? Have a look: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1989/Image-Processing-for-Dummies-with-C-and-GDI-Part-1

Answer (score 3):

With this Function should work:

```
Public Function GetPicturePart(ByVal SourceImage As Image, ByVal Region As Rectangle) As Bitmap
    Dim ImagePart As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Region.Width, Region.Height)
    Using G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(ImagePart)
        Dim TargetRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, Region.Width, Region.Height)
        Dim SourceRect As Rectangle = Region
        G.DrawImage(SourceImage, TargetRect, SourceRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
    End Using
    Return ImagePart
End Function
```

I think this function is self-describing. ;)

Source: [Get Picture Part](http://dotnet-snippets.de/dns/vbnet-bildausschnitt-auslesen-SID340.aspx)